# Excel VBA Merge two files with selected Column and Row transfer to one worksheet base on its header

Tags: vba, excel

I have assigned a job by my boss two weeks ago. Which is using VBA Excel to create a macro merging two different excel(xls) files into one (header) worksheet.

This is the worksheet with (**header**) given!

[**Username**],[**Name**],[**attempt**],[**Started on**],[**Score**],[**Quiz(Jan-23-2013)**],[**Completed**]

This is the two files given

**1.CWPI Topic 1 Assessment**

```
               A         B      C        D       E          F
```

**1** (row number)  [**Username**],[**Name**],[**attempt**],[**Started on**],[**Score**],[**Quiz(Jan-23-2013)**]

**2** (row number)  [**111111111**],[**Matt**],[**0000002**],[***_*__*_*_2013**],[**00100**],[***_*____*Attended*__*_*_**]

**2.CWPI Topic 1**

```
               A         B      C        D       E          F
```

**1** (row number)  [**Username**],[**Name**],[**attempt**],[**Started on**],[**Score**],[**Completed**]

**2** (row number)  [**123456789**],[**Rose**],[**0000001**],[***_*__*_*_2013**],[**00080**],[**Completed**]

Two files above have no specific location!!

1. I need to select two files with selected column and last row and transfer the data    according to the header. Because one of it contain different header.
2. But must make sure it collect last row of data. Because sometimes might be 1000 row of data sometimes might be 2000...
3. Lastly i need to delete the duplicate
   I've been searching for high and low of all kind of solutions,getfile,vlookup,copy&paste. I just getting bit confused. Any suggest or solution will be much appreciated ><.

Sorry for the late update, this is what i have did so far, below is the code that i'm using

```
Sub GetFile()

Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim copywb As Workbook
Dim destinationwb As Workbook

'## Open both workbook first:

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="CWPI Topic 1 Assessment")

If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

Set copywb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS",    Title:="CWPI Topic 1 Assessment")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set destinationwb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

'Now, copy what you want from copywb:
copywb.Sheets("Report").Range("A1:G2").Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Now, paste to destinationwb worksheet:
destinationwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial

'Close copywb:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
copywb.Close 
End Sub
```

Now the problem i'm facing is when i try to select column A Row 2  to Column G Row 2 and till the end with data by using code below:

```
copywb.Sheets("Report").Range("A1:G2").Copy  
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

It comes out run error "91"
Object variables or with block variable not set

Thank you so much for any suggestions

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far? You said that you've `been searching for high and low of all kind of solutions`. It'd be nice to see your attempt. :)

Comment: Just updated my code, apologies for late update.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the code. What is your last column for each sheet? Is it Column G? Or is this variable as well? This is because we have to make it flexible. I see already that your last column is either `[Quiz...` or `[Completed...`. Is this correct?

Comment: My last Column is H. I just need to select and copy the entire row with data till Column G. But the last row data might be vary.For the last column (column H), i need to copy and paste to another column. Thank you so much><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
Sub GetFile()

Dim Book1Path As Variant, Book2Path As Variant
Dim SourceWB As Workbook, DestWB As Workbook
Dim lRow As Long

'## Open both workbook first:

Book1Path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="CWPI Topic 1 Assessment")
If Book1Path = False Then Exit Sub
Set Source = Workbooks.Open(Book1Path)

Book2Path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="CWPI Topic 1")
If Book2Path = False Then Exit Sub
Set DestWB = Workbooks.Open(Book2Path)

'Turn off screen updating and alerts.
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

'Copy.
With SourceWB.Sheets("Report")
    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:G" & lRow).Copy
End With

'Paste.
DestWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
SourceWB.Close

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: If Book2Path = False Then Exit Sub. For this code it showed type mismatch. Sorry i'm bit new to vba exel ><

Comment: Updated the above. Please try again.